# How to use option Arbitrtaion=WaitExternal in MySQL Cluster?

Tags: mysql, high-availability

I'm currently reading MySQL Reference Manual and notice that there an option of NDB config -- Arbitrtaion=WaitExternal. The question is how to use this option and how to implement an external cluster manager?

```
The Arbitration parameter also makes it possible to configure arbitration in
such a way that the cluster waits until after the time determined by Arbitrat- 
ionTimeout has passed for an external cluster manager application to perform 
arbitration instead of handling arbitration internally. This can be done by 
setting Arbitration = WaitExternal in the [ndbd default] section of the config.ini
file. For best results with the WaitExternal setting, it is recommended that
ArbitrationTimeout be 2 times as long as the interval required by the external 
cluster manager to perform arbitration.
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of git annotate and some searching of original design docs says the following:

When the arbitrator is about to send an arbitration message to the arbitrator it will instead issue the following log message:

- case ArbitCode::WinWaitExternal:{
- char buf[8*4*2+1];
- sd->mask.getText(buf);
- BaseString::snprintf(m_text, m_text_len,
- "Continuing after wait for external arbitration, "
- "nodes: %s", buf);
- break;
- }

So e.g.
Continuing after wait for external arbitration, nodes: 1,2

The external clusterware should check for this message
at the same interval as the ArbitrationTimeout.
When it discovers this message, the external cluster ware
should kill the data node that it decides to lose the
arbitration.

This kill will be noted by the NDB data nodes and will
decide the matter which node is to survive.